# Health Issues at Open Mics

Tags: microphones

I'm starting an open mic session at a new venue. With Covid in mind, what precautions could be taken regarding letting others use particular mics?

At previous venues mics were provided, but I (and several others) always used our own. At this venue, there's only one mic, and I don't want all and sundry using mine, but am still concerned about the risk involved when everyone will be using the one mic.

Comment: I wonder whether there are any scientific studies about transmission via shared mic; I'll bet there are. My armchair scientist says that Covid in particular might be more of a threat when airborne than after coming to rest on the mic (i.e. it's actually the front row that's more at risk), but there's probably any number of unpleasant bugs eager to jump into anyone who's mouthing the mic...

Comment: If you can transfer it easily hand to mouth - which judging by the 'Wash your hands:Sanitise' campaigns is common - then mike to mouth is going to be just as easy. I've avoided karaoke since 2020 & I'm not thinking of starting up again any time soon, with BA.5 now rampant & Centaurus hot on its tail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a medical question, not musical.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - what a surprise. It's about musical *practice*.

Comment: I've voted to leave open, but I think @CarlWitthoft's objection on "medical" grounds is compelling. My feeling is there's enough musical content and value to the site to keep the question open, but it's a boundary case at least. It would be great if someone would ask a doctor and post the response here.

Comment: @Aaron - it's an issue that surely affects many musos gong about their daily business, whether open mic, or even recording studio, and live gigs too. How does one 'vote to stay open'?

Comment: What type of mic are you using?

Comment: @user87626 - they're generally the usual SM58.

Comment: @Tim so it's a handheld dynamic mic?

Comment: @user87626 - yes, wouldn't use any other sort in that situation!

Comment: @Tim "Leave Open" is a voting option in the Close Review queue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you can't clean the mic capsule itself, or any integral pop-shield…

One 'mickey mouse nose' foam pop shield per user, which can be sanitised afterwards. Alcohol wipes for the mic body, between users.
Or, the cheap & cheerful, if not great sonically - a thin baggie over the whole thing, inverted & discarded after each use.
Might be better to leave the 58 at home for this & use the 57 with pop shields/baggies.

As per [Shoeps - Microphone use & Covid-19](https://schoeps.de/en/knowledge/knowledge-base/microphone-use-covid-19.html)

Violawave designed a UV box to sanitise mics inside 5 minutes - might be OK if you have two mics - [How do you sanitise your microphones against Covid-19?](https://www.studiospares.com/news/How-do-you-sanitise-your-microphones-against-Covid-19)

Shure have detailed info on cleaning specific mic types - [How Should I Clean My Microphone?](https://service.shure.com/s/article/how-should-i-clean-my-microphone?language=en_US)

Oooh, late find - Mic "condoms" - disposable fabric covers, eg [Amazon US link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0756V1WNZ)

…and, of course, hand gel on the side of the stage, for use on the way on & on the way off.

Answer (score 2):

I found this website useful. ([https://www.dpamicrophones.com/mic-university/proper-mic-hygiene#:~:text=To%20disinfect%20handheld%20and%20pencil,on%20surfaces%20to%20kill%20germs.](https://www.dpamicrophones.com/mic-university/proper-mic-hygiene#:%7E:text=To%20disinfect%20handheld%20and%20pencil,on%20surfaces%20to%20kill%20germs.))

"To disinfect handheld and pencil microphones, wipe down their surface with a cloth moistened sparingly with an isopropyl alcohol and water solution*. Make sure that no isopropyl alcohol comes into contact with the microphone membrane.

- Pure isopropyl alcohol evaporates too quickly on surfaces to kill germs. By adding 20% water, its disinfectant properties will be extended for enough time to work properly."

I think you can also just use alcohol wipes, but I'm not sure how effective they will be.

I suppose you could try and disinfect the mic regularly while it's not being used, but it might be a bit of a hassle. Otherwise you could just install one of those disposable hygiene mic covers. I found a few options on Google.
[image]

You can clean the cables by rubbing with olive/coconut oil. Also, don't spray liquid on or near the microphone capsule or electronics, and don't use bleach. (https://www.greatchurchsound.com/blog/how-to-clean-and-disinfect-a-microphone)

Also check this website out: https://www.pro-tools-expert.com/production-expert-1/2020/3/10/how-and-why-to-clean-a-dynamic-microphone-tip on how to clean your mic.